# How to join 2 DB tables and perform GROUP BY at the same time?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

`Equipment(PK int id,nvarchar name)`

`EquipmentAction(int EquipmentId, datetime Timestamp)`

I want to display the earliest `Timestamp` for each named `Equipment` and I cannot figure it out.

- I can do `select EquipmentId, min(TimeStamp) from EquipmentAction group by(EquipmentId)`
- I can do `select e.name, a.TimeStamp from Equipment e inner join EquipmentAction a on e.id=a.EquipmentId`

But I can't see how to combine these two ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the `group by`, like this:

```
select e.name, min(a.TimeStamp)
from Equipment e inner join
     EquipmentAction a
     on e.id = a.EquipmentId
group by e.name
```

Comment: OK the issue was I was trying to `group` on the key, not `name`. I'm still not really sure why, but this is perfect